# Folders got converted to files Windows 8.1

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, data-recovery

My PC didn't get closed down correctly so windows had to repair my HDD. After windows repaired my HDD it left me with some files that had the same name as the directory's that were there before. I know the file system hasn't been deleted cause the HDD still uses the same amount of space as it did before. My HDD isn't corrupted.

**Screenshot 1:**

[image: https://imgur.com/8lR1DiP]

**Screenshot 2:**

[image: https://imgur.com/VnBVbsA]

Comment: Do the folders have a filetype extension? Try changing the extension to what it was before. What happens?

Comment: What happens when you double-click on those converted files(previously folders) ??

Comment: There isn't any extensions and when I double-click the "select a program to run this file type" menu comes.

Comment: Be very careful that you no longer write to that hard disk. Leave it on (no reboots), don't work on it, disable automatic processes, disable hibernation/sleep. You don't say so, but are all the files that were in those folders still present? They may not be, although their data is still on the disk. In that case with new writes, the OS may think the sectors occupied by those files are available for writing again. Hence my warning. You need good file recovery software and you need to verify that every write/recover action you are going to take will have the desired result.

Comment: attach some screenshots!

Comment: The files still exists on the HDD as you can see in screenshot 1

Comment: But i can't access the files